# Auto-increment includes Date

Tags: mysql

Hi can I ask if how can I for example 2018-03-18 I want to take the 03 and combine it to 18 and add for example 1 the result should be 03181 make it auto increment like that is it possible?

Comment: That's not really an auto-increment. I think this is a so-called "XY question", research that term and improve your question.

Comment: okay will do search that term and ill go back here to improve my question Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that this complex solution is something which you really want. You need this incrementing column as a table key? What's wrong with having composite key from two columns, first from date and second being simple integer?

Comment: Hi I need this because  i need a row in the table named job number which contains the last two digit of the current year, the month in numeric form, the day and a number.

Comment: You need to improve your question in order to get help. Do you need an SQL UPDATE sentence to calculate field JOB_NUMBER using another field DATE? Is JOB_NUMBER used as KEY in that table? Do you need to generate that key BEFORE inserting a record?

Answer (score 0):

Please make use of functions in this case. You can have a custom function "`getNextCustomSeq`" which contains the logic and will return the next sequence value.

Comment: you mean im should add a trigger?